# Calculate Directory from file full path in JSON directory tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

```
{
  "path": null,//should be calculated back as: "photos"
  "size": 600,
  "type": "directory",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": null,//it should be calculated as: "photos/summer"
      "size": 400,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": null,//should be calculated as :"photos/summer/june"
          "size": 400,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg",
              "name": "windsurf.jpg",
              "size": 400,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": null,//should be calculated as: "photos/winter"
      "size": 200,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": null,// should be calculated as: "photos/winter/january"
          "size": 200,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/ski.png",
              "name": "ski.png",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".png"
            },
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg",
              "name": "snowboard.jpg",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a json that represents directory structure. All "file" property in json has absolute path assigned to property "path".
But each sub-directories/directories is missing "path" value. Each subdirectories which have path=null needs to be assigned path on the basis of deepest child(type="file") which has absolute path defined.(Expected output is commented as **//should be calculated as:**)

I tried iterative approach, but problem is I have to traverse json from depth to top(ie. deepest children towards parent) . Can someone recommend cleaner approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `path` by taking `name` property and iterate `children`, if exist and hand over the last path.

```js
function setPath(object, path = '') {
    (object.children || []).forEach(o => {
        var temp = setPath(o);
        if (temp) object.path = temp.slice(0, temp.lastIndexOf('/'));
    });
    return object.path;
}

var data = { path: null, size: 600, type: "directory", children: [{ path: null, size: 400, type: "directory", children: [{ path: null, size: 400, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg", name: "windsurf.jpg", size: 400, type: "file", extension: ".jpg" }] }] }, { path: null, size: 200, type: "directory", children: [{ path: null, size: 200, type: "directory", children: [{ path: "photos/winter/january/ski.png", name: "ski.png", size: 100, type: "file", extension: ".png" }, { path: "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg", name: "snowboard.jpg", size: 100, type: "file", extension: ".jpg" }] }] }] };

setPath(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is: The `name` property is just a label or display name, it can be any arbitary string. Updated the json format, where name is not available at all.

Comment: Thank you @Nina. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
function setPath(obj,path){
    let currentPath=path+'/'+obj.name;
    obj.path=currentPath;
    if(obj.children && obj.children.length){
        obj.children.forEach(item=>this.setPath(item,currentPath))
    }
}
```

call this function with the object and path name as '/'
eg `setPath(obj,'/')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is: The name property is just a label or display name, it can be any arbitary string. Updated the json format, where name is not available at all

Comment: So on basis of which label or field name we need to create the path?, if the name field is not present.

Comment: Thanks. On the basis of "path" which "type"= "file" has.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt get it , so how will i get the directory name eg"photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg" in this the photos and summer are directories right? how will I get those names?